# Visual Studio 2010 disable mouseover to display hidden window

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Usually there are tabs like Toolbox, Properties, Error List, Output, Find results... on the side of screen. When I mouseover to those hidden windows, the window will popup. Is there any way to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: I actually have not seen this behavior.

Comment: Do you have auto hide turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go in **Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows** and uncheck "**Show auto-hidden windows on mouse over**".